# GCP Container Engine Build Triggers - $REPO_NAME includes "github"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I'm trying to setup build triggers on GCP but I'm finding that the $REPO_NAME variable they provide when configuring your image name is a bit counter-intuitive. Rather than it being the actual repository name, they include both the Git provider (in my case Github) and the organisation name, like so: `github-[organisation]-[repo]`

Does anyone know a way I can just have the repository name? Ideally, my final GCR image would be at:

`gcr.io/[gcp-project]/[repo-name-as-appears-on-github]:[tag-number]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available at this time. The existing list of substitutions is available here: https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/concepts/build-requests#substitutions

Comment: It'd be really nice to have only the repo name.